# SPARQL Select two columns

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql

I'm new to SPARQL and I'm trying to select two or more data properties from entity.
I have **Artist** entity which has two data properties (**id** and **name**). I'm trying to obtain a result like this:

```
 id         Name
 0         Artist 1
 1         Artist 2
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
 id         Name
 0         Artist 1
 0         Artist 2
 1         Artist 1
 1         Artist 2
```

Here is my SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX wits:   <http://wits.org/song/> 
SELECT ?name, ?id 
FROM <http://wits.org/song> 
WHERE
{ 
    <http://wits.org/song/Artist>  wits:Name ?name .
    <http://wits.org/song/Artist>  wits:ID ?id 
}
```

Here is RDF implementation of Artist Class:

```
<!ENTITY www "http://www.wits.org/" >
<owl:Class rdf:about="&www;Artist">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&www;song#ID"/>
                <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&xsd;unsignedInt"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&www;song#Name"/>
                <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
                <owl:onDataRange rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
```

This is INSERT command which was executed previously:

```
PREFIX wits: <http://wits.org/song/>
        INSERT DATA INTO <http://wits.org/song> {
        wits:Artist wits:Name "Artist 2"
        wits:ID 1 .
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.
125125

Comment: Duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/8757/sparql-select-two-columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are inserting the following data.

```
    INSERT DATA INTO <http://wits.org/song> {
        wits:Artist wits:Name "Artist 0"; wits:ID 0 .
        wits:Artist wits:Name "Artist 1"; wits:ID 1 .
    }
```

which is wrong because `wits:Artist` would have both names and both ids, you need to give different URIs to each Artist and provide the class as `rdf:type`.

The right way according to your ontology would be ...

```
    INSERT DATA INTO <http://wits.org/song> {
        wits:Artist0 a wits:Artist; wits:Name "Artist 0"; wits:ID 0 .
        wits:Artist1 a wits:Artist; wits:Name "Artist 1"; wits:ID 1 .
    }
```

`a` is equivalent to `rdf:type`. In here we're saying that `wits:Artist0` is type of class `wits:Artist` with name `Artist 0` and id `0`.